# Woocommerce: Backorder only for certain roles

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I want to activate backorders (possibility to buy products without stock) in woocommerce but only for a specific user role.

This option is now on woocommerce but it works for all users.

Comment: If you want to achieve this programmatically (though hooking of WordPress and WooCommerce filters) you can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319823/woocommerce-products-allow-backorders-only-for-specific-user-roles

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to edit the user role  , [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) ,

You can customize the controls for particular roles and uncheck unwanted permissions from user roles.

Go to **Users -> User Role Editor** to change the role permissions

Comment: You could make this answer more complete by also mentioning the specific role(s) that relate to the backorders, as there seem to be quite a large number of roles that can be selected through the plugin.