# WooCommerce custom conditional function throws critical error on product update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I made custom conditional function that check product stock quantity is below zero:

```
function is_product_below_zero_stock( $stock_qty ) {
    global $product;
    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if ($stock_qty < 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Based on [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321847/3730754) from my previous question, I used my conditional function in:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status' );
function filter_product_stock_status( $stock_status) {
    if ( is_allowed_user_role()  && 'outofstock' === $stock_status ) {
        $stock_status = 'onbackorder';
    } 
    elseif( is_product_below_zero_stock( $stock_qty ) && 'onbackorder' != $stock_status  ) {
        $stock_status = 'outofstock';
    }
    return $stock_status;
}
```

I get a critical error come when I update product in backend.
What i can do for fix this?

---

**Edit** - added missing `is_allowed_user_role()` function:

```
// Custom conditional function targeting specific user roles
function is_allowed_user_role() {
    $targeted_roles = array('administrator', 'shop_manager'); // Here define your targeted user roles
    return (bool) array_intersect( wp_get_current_user()->roles, $targeted_roles );
}
```

Comment: **1)** `is_allowed_user_role()` function is missing. **2)** If you could add the error message from the error logs, that would clarify a lot. **3)** your passing the `$stock_qty` variable to the `is_product_below_zero_stock` function, but then overwrites it with `$stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();`. **4)** 
Instead of posting multiple questions in a row on SO within hours. Make sure previous questions are resolved before opening new ones, because that makes it very unclear.

Comment: 1. It's not missing.
2. I cannot see file to generate now, will update later with info from file
3. fixed thanks.
4. I have only 1 opened, that i voted for close

Comment: **1)** _" It's not missing"._ Where in your question is the code of the `is_allowed_user_role()` function? I only see the call. **2)** Why you should vote on your own question(s) to close it? if your question is no longer needed, just delete it instead. **3)** Rather than stating that you will update your question later, do that right away or just ask your question later. The way your question is now written will only ensure that you receive downvotes and that your question will eventually be closed by people who do not find your question clear enough to be able to answer it.

Comment: Added the missing function `is_allowed_user_role()` that was located on an answer to OP's previous question…

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code. To avoid this error use the following instead:

```
function is_product_below_zero_stock( $product ) {
    return $product->get_stock_quantity() < 0 ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_stock_status( $stock_status, $product ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) 
        return $stock_status;

    if ( is_allowed_user_role()  && 'outofstock' === $stock_status ) {
        $stock_status = 'onbackorder';
    } 
    elseif( is_product_below_zero_stock( $product ) && 'onbackorder' != $stock_status  ) {
        $stock_status = 'outofstock';
    }
    return $stock_status;
}
```

It should better works…

Comment: Thank you sir, but this not give a result and all woo pages are broken